# installation of zen-cart 1.5: renaming admin folder and redirect error

Tags: zen-cart

I installing Zen Cart v1.5, and am at the last steps of the process where I'm required to rename the admin folder. I renamed the folder, and tried to access the admin section by manually typing in the address with the renamed folder. However, it keeps trying to redirect back to the original admin url, giving me the following error:

> The requested URL /admin/alert_page.php was not found on this server.

(alert.php is just the page that warns me I need to rename the admin folder -- it's trying to redirect back to this page, even though I renamed the folder.)

This seems to indicate some error with a config file, though the instructions for installation explicitly said that with the current version, it is not necessary to change the config files. (Though, just for good measure I examined the includes/configuration.php file to see if there was an admin folder value I could set, but didn't see any).

I also reloaded the browser cache, to no avail.

Comment: Was this Zen Cart 1.5.1 or 1.5.0?  Look in <YOUR_RENAMED_ADMIN>/includes/configure.php for the string "admin".

Answer (score 0):

Based on where your root zen-cart is installed, you'll want to edit your configure.php file which holds the path to tell Zen cart where the 'ADMIN' directory is located.

For example, I renamed my admin folder to 'control', so I would look for the configure.php file at:

/home/user/public_html/**control**/includes/configure.php

Look for the defines:

```
define('DIR_WS_ADMIN', '/admin/');
define('DIR_WS_CATALOG', '/');
define('DIR_WS_HTTPS_ADMIN', '/admin/');
define('DIR_WS_HTTPS_CATALOG', '/');
```

You'll want to change this to reflect the new folder name you renamed your ADMIN folder to:

```
define('DIR_WS_ADMIN', '/control/');
define('DIR_WS_CATALOG', '/');
define('DIR_WS_HTTPS_ADMIN', '/control/');
define('DIR_WS_HTTPS_CATALOG', '/');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same question and solution for it!
https://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?203681-it-doesn-t-work-after-I-renamed-admin-folder-name